# Editing a Phone Call's 'Quick View Form'

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2013

I find the Quick View Form for Phone Call activity non-editable (save button disabled) in my installation of Dynamics CRM 2013 (trial version downloaded from Microsoft site). However, [**this**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HILwHWxfefQ) video describes the said form as editable (watch from 10:35 - 12:35 mins). So how can I edit this form?

Moreover, it is described in the video that a said Quick View Form is used to create a quick phone call record in the social pane of the entity form. How can we use the Quick View Form like this (create quick record) for our custom entity? Or is it only a built-in feature for out of the box social pane?

Comment: That's a really good question - I tried it myself in an online trial and did hit exactly the same roadblocks: The standard form as shown in the vid is not editable and a custom activity does allow to compose a Quick Create Form (and mark the entity as quick-creatable) but will always redirect to the Main Form when selected from the Social Pane.

Comment: Seems the video was recorded using beta version of the CRM application and later the Microsoft decided to revert back the functionality. May be ... :)

Comment: @Filburt Regarding what you mentioned about Activity entities and 'Quick Create Form', it is clearly stated in the Customization Guide that **"Activity entities do not support quick create forms"**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was changed in the final version of CRM, the video uses the beta version. I watched the whole series a while ago and noticed this and some other small differences between the beta and the released version.

Comment: What I understood from your answer is that editing feature for Phone Call's quick view form removed from the final version?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT TOP 1000 [FormXmlManaged]
      ,[Version]
      ,[FormId]
      ,[PublishedOn]
      ,[FormXml]
      ,[CanBeDeleted]
      ,[OrganizationId]
      ,[ComponentState]
      ,[IsCustomizable]
      ,[OverwriteTime]
      ,[IsManaged]
      ,[Description]
      ,[Name]
      ,[AncestorFormId]
      ,[Type]
      ,[SupportingSolutionId]
      ,[SolutionId]
      ,[VersionNumber]
      ,[ObjectTypeCode]
      ,[FormIdUnique]
      ,[IsDefault]
      ,[FormPresentation]
      ,[FormActivationState]
      ,[IntroducedVersion]
      ,[IsAIRMerged]
      ,[IsTabletEnabled]
      ,[UniqueName]
      ,[IsDesktopEnabled]
  FROM [Main_MSCRM].[dbo].[SystemFormBase]
    where FormId = '8E0B7C1E-F5A0-4E7D-B04D-4CA8D5C5CA80'

  update  [Main_MSCRM].[dbo].[SystemFormBase]
  set IsManaged = 1
  where FormId = '8E0B7C1E-F5A0-4E7D-B04D-4CA8D5C5CA80'
```